# WatiN "Unable to cast COM object" exception

Tags: c#, browser, object, com, watin

from time to time, my monitoring application dies for no obvious reason. It seems like "mshtml.HTMLDocument" resource isn't available. Anyone else experienced something similar? Thanks in advance.

Error message:

```
14.04.2011 18:26:37 -> Test 1.2 (Subscriber type requests), error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'mshtml.HTMLDocument'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3050F55F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Error stack trace:

```
14.04.2011 18:26:37 -> Test 1.2 (Subscriber type requests), trace:    at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEWaitForComplete.WaitForFramesToComplete(IHTMLDocument2 maindocument)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEWaitForComplete.WaitForFramesToComplete(IHTMLDocument2 maindocument)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEWaitForComplete.WaitForCompleteOrTimeout()
   at WatiN.Core.WaitForCompleteBase.DoWait()
   at WatiN.Core.IE.WaitForComplete(Int32 waitForCompleteTimeOut)
   at WatiN.Core.Browser.GoTo(Uri url)
   at WatiN.Core.Browser.GoTo(String url)
   at WebMonitor.Tests.Execute() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting. I have put a a re-try around the cast. This exception is probably caused by timing. Hope the re-try will fix it. Will be part of the next release or get the latest code from SourceForge.

Comment: I having this problem on release in a xp machine with ie7 if it helps to detect the problem.

Comment: A link to the fix would have been helpful!