# Is it possible to use WatiN 2.1 with MvcContrib.WatiN?

Tags: watin, mvccontrib

With WatiN 1.3, the IE object constructor throws an exception on my machine. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811340/watin-error-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-mshtml-htmldocumentclass-to-int).

WatiN 2.1 doesn't have the same issue. However, I'm using MvcContrib.WatiN which appears to depend on WatiN 1.3. Is it possible to use WatiN 2.1 instead of 1.3 with MvcContrib? If so, how? WatiN 1.3 is a very old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the current MvcContrib version. But since it's open source you can always do the leg work yourself to make it work. You'll have to get the latest MvcContrib source code [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and modify the WatiN.Core reference on the MvcContrib.TestHelper.WatiN project to use the WatiN.Core.dll v2.1. Then recompile MvcContrib.TestHelper.WatiN (use this new compiled dll in your project).

One caveat: You'll have to rework JavaScriptExecutor.GetWindow() a bit (within the MvcContrib.TestHelper.WatiN namespace) to be able to recompile it. WatiN 2.1 does not have the HtmlDocument class in Document anymore (not sure where that logic went to).